# Design advice for restful darts-game communication

Tags: rest, session, design-patterns, microservices

I am thinking of a simple x01 darts game rest api for two players. I am pretty clear on how to implement the darts business logic. But I struggle thinking about a session-like communication between the players in order to let player a wait for player b to finish its turn.
After my research I did not came up with a pattern to apply here, nor if its a restful antipattern. So any advice is appreciated how something like mentioned could be realised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I decided to go with [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).